# I can't reach JSON value Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I can't reach my returned JSON data value. I'm using get method for reaching and server returns the JSON with 200 but when I try to reach JSON value it gives error.

My JSON:

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "userName": "Mehmet",
            "email": "personal@test.com",
            "sys_role": 3,
            "tckn": "00000000000",
            "fk_parkID": 81
        }
    ],
    "parks": [
        {
            "parkID": 1,
            "parkName": "Park Name",
            "latitude": 42,
            "longitude": 29,
            "fk_regionID": 2
        }, // 107 more parks like the up one.
    ]
}
```

I've tried this for reaching "userName" value from "user".

```
var selectedUserInfo;
var parksInfo;

selectUser(id) async { // This is selecting a person for doing some process on his/her account.
    var result = CallApi().getData('admin/user/${id}', _setHeaders());

    selectedUserInfo = jsonDecode(result.body)["user"][0]["userName"];
    parksInfo = jsonDecode(result.body)["parks"];
    setState(() {

    });
}
```

When I

```
print(selectedUserInfo)
```

it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData()` method is probably an asynchronous method (Future).

If you don't wait for it, the result will be null, so the selectedUserInfo.

You should add the `await` keyword like this :

`var result = await CallApi().getData('admin/user/${id}', _setHeaders());`

I hope that will solve your issue

Comment: Oh thank you so much! It's overlooked.